# How to add pop-up action when closing a screen in pos

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-10

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaDSX.jpg

How do you add a pop up confirmation on the header action buttons in odoo. Attached image with a markup. TIA

Comment: Describe what you have already tried.

Comment: Nothing i can't find it in gui.js been looking for it